# How to show org-clock (and org-pomodoro) timer in mode-line?

Tags: org-mode, mode-line

I tried the following methods in my custom mode-line, but they all failed.

```el
(setq mode-line-format
      (:propertize
       ;; TODO: concatenate the long string.
       ;; global-mode-string
       ;; (t org-mode-line-string org-timer-mode-line-string)
       ;; (t org-timer-mode-line-string) ; org-timer default time 25, (Pomodoro time management technique)
       ;; (:eval org-clock-mode-line-timer)
       ;; face (:foreground "cyan" :weight 'bold)
       ))
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, the org-clock should appear on the mode line out of the box. Could you try it with `emacs -Q`? Or are you clocking in in an unconventional way (maybe with a 3rd party package) which would inhibit (or simply not trigger) the insertion of the time into the mode line?

Comment: I know it can be used out of box, but I need to add it in my custom `mode-line-format`, so I ask this question.

Comment: great idea, Maybe I should inspect the org-clock indicator in `mode-line-format` with `emacs -Q`. So I can find out what Org-mode do.
UPDATE:
this failed.

Comment: Apparently, the functions you should have a look at are `org-clock-update-mode-line` and its child `org-clock-get-clock-string`, in `org-clock.el`.

Comment: Ah, and the variable `org-mode-line-string` is the indicator you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, now org-clock appears in mode-line, but why it does not disappear after clock out? weird.

Comment: Maybe you will have to reset the mode-line value in the clock-out hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @T.Verron 's coments hint, then I got this. And it work.

```el
(setq mode-line-format
      (:propertize
       (t org-mode-line-string)
       face (:foreground "cyan" :weight 'bold)))

(add-hook 'org-clock-out-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (setq org-mode-line-string nil)
             (force-mode-line-update)))
```