# How to show git repo status info in mode-line

Tags: mode-line, git, mode-line-format

Here is my current custom, but I don't know how to customize its face. And it
only shows branch name, no other status info.

```lisp
(setq-default
 mode-line-format
 (quote
  ((:eval
    (if vc-mode
        (progn
          (list
           (propertize " ⭠"
                       'face '(:foreground "sky blue"))
           ;; TODO: propertize this. set face height to 75
           `(vc-mode vc-mode)
           ))))
   )))
```

I hope someone can give out a better solution.
Or at least tell me how to custom my upper status `(vc-mode vc-mode)` face.

Comment: Can you further suggest how to display the current branch in the dired modeline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In git, if you hover the mouse over the mode line portion which starts "Git", you get more information such as the branch and update status.

Looks like you've asked about mode line customization before [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13652/how-to-customize-mode-line-format?rq=1) and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12840/how-to-show-org-clock-and-org-pomodoro-timer-in-mode-line), so you should understand how to set values in the mode line.

To get the status of the file, the function you want is:

```
(vc-state (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))
```

And to get the branch:

```
(vc-working-revision (buffer-file-name (current-buffer)))
```

Comment: For me (vc-working-revision (buffer-file-name (current-buffer))) return a hash number instead of a branch name like "master"

Comment: @run_the_race - ok. Basically the command `git rev-parse HEAD` is run. GNU Emacs is open source, feel free to suggest changes to it, or post another solution. The particular file is to changer is http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/vc/vc-git.el#n349

Comment: @rocky What about show git's branch name in mode line on Dired mode?

Comment: @a_subscriber haven't a clue. Maybe you should post that as its own question if you are looking for an answer.

Comment: @rocky I found. This help https://github.com/10sr/git-ps1-mode-el