# How to display org-pomodoro timer in mode-line

Tags: org-mode

I see a video on youtube which display pomodoro clock  in mode line

[image]

I installed [lolownia/org-pomodoro: pomodoro technique for org-mode](https://github.com/lolownia/org-pomodoro) but it's clock does not show on the mode line

Alternatively, tried the answer [How to show org-clock (and org-pomodoro) timer in mode-line? - Emacs Stack Exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12840/how-to-show-org-clock-and-org-pomodoro-timer-in-mode-line)

Unfortunatley, it's wrong to report error when start emacs.

I found the the rainbow is [nyan-mode: Nyan Cat for Emacs!](https://github.com/TeMPOraL/nyan-mode)  which just display the scroll of the buffer.

How could I show a basic orgclock in mode line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title of the question differs from the last sentence in the body of the question that states:  "*How could I show a basic orgclock in mode line?*".  This answer addresses that last component of the question body.

`org-mode` uses the `global-mode-string` which is incorporated into the default mode-line used by Emacs.  To the extent a user has a custom `mode-line-format` that differs from the default, the `global-mode-string` may or may not be included as part of that user customization.  To see the `org-clock` in the mode-line as part of a custom setup, a user may wish to ensure that the `global-mode-string` is incorporated.  Alternatively, the user may wish to use `org-timer-mode-line-string` and set-up a mechanism to add/remove it when turning the clock on/off.